# Yii - errors with AR and FK when inserting

Tags: activerecord, foreign-keys, yii

I have simple unit test:

```
    $newItem = new Item;
    $itemTitle = "New item 1";
    $newItem->setAttributes(
        array(
            'part' => '0000',
            'type_id' => 1,
            'category_id' => 1,
            'title' => $itemTitle,
            'title_template' => '',
            'color' => 'black',
            'size' => 40,
            'desc' => 'Test New Item 1',
        )
    );
    $this->assertTrue($newItem->save(false));
```

When I ran this test, I've got an error:

```
CDbException: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wh_test`.`tbl_item`, CONSTRAINT `fk_goods_type` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_type` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_item` (`part`, `type_id`, `category_id`, `title`, `title_template`, `color`, `size`, `desc`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7)

/var/www/yii/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:354
/var/www/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php:1014
/var/www/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php:787
/var/www/wh/wh/protected/tests/unit/ItemTest.php:18
```

I try to manually insert it into the database and all is OK:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_item` VALUES (0, '0000', 1, 1, 'New item 1', '', 'black', 40, 'Test New Item 1', NULL);
```

What's wrong? It seems to incorrect relations but I am a Yii newbie.
Here is a relatioins() of Item model:

```
    return array(
        'goods' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Goods', 'item_id'),
        'type' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Type', 'type_id'),
        'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id'),
        'descTemplate' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'DescTemplate', 'desc_template_id'),
    );
```

and SQL CREATE TABLE:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wh`.`tbl_item` ( 
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `part` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
 `type_id` INT NOT NULL, 
 `category_id` INT NOT NULL, 
 `title` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , 
 `title_template` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , 
 `color` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL , 
 `size` INT NOT NULL , 
 `desc` TEXT NOT NULL , 
 `desc_template_id` INT NULL , 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
 CONSTRAINT `fk_goods_type` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`type_id` ) 
  REFERENCES `wh`.`tbl_type` (`id` ) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE 
  ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
 CONSTRAINT `fk_goods_category` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`category_id` ) 
  REFERENCES `wh`.`tbl_category` (`id` ) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE 
  ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
 CONSTRAINT `fk_goods_desc_template` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`desc_template_id`) 
  REFERENCES `wh`.`tbl_desc_template` (`id`) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE 
  ON DELETE RESTRICT 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: can you tell what rows exist in your tbl_type table? It seems it doesn't have the row with id as 1.

Comment: I have added a test row (id:1, name:test) before executing unit test

Comment: ok. I see that you are not passing the primary key (id) for the table when you set the attributes; nor have you declared id as auto increment. I think your problem should go if you declare id as auto increment. Before that you can check if that's the problem by also setting id in the setAttributes method.

Comment: I've tried to call setAttributes() with declaring id but no changes and there is no `id` field in error message. Foreign key tables is simple as table(id,name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was be problem with test database. I have synchronized data with work database and all test was passed.

Comment: since you have solved it, accept your own answer, helps future users